# Can i use more than role name in new ClaimTypes.Role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

i have this methode add cookies with ClaimType Role

```
private async void AddCookies(string role)
    {
     var claim = new List<Claim>
     {
       new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role , role.ToString()),
     }
    }
```

and this my database [table Users And Roels And Users Roles every user have more than role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQz4q.png)

i try to use array but not work with me like this example

```
 private async void AddCookies(string[] role)
        {
         var claim = new List<Claim>
         {
           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role , role.ToString()),
         }
        }
```

Comment: Add a role for each string in the array.

Comment: yes i added by not work :)

Comment: That's not what your code sample shows though. You're trying to put the entire array into _one_ role. You should be putting each string _in_ the array into its own single role.

Comment: ok i can use foreach inside |  new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role , here) | ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding a role for every element of the array, but you pass the whole array as parameter in Claim() constructor. You have to itterate through the array of roles and create for every single role new claim.

```
    private async void AddCookies(string[] roles)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();

        foreach(var role in roles)
        {      
            var claim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role);

            claims.Add(claim);
        }       
    }
```